# Оптимизация изображений

Tags: html, вёрстка, оптимизация-сайтов

Привет. Встал вопросы оптимизации изображений на сайте. Особенно интересует оптимизация png-24. Пробовал оптимизировать через онлайн-сервис tunypng.com, но результат оказался печальным. Хотелось бы, что-то более настраиваемое.

Скажите, как вы используете инструменты для оптимизации?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File Optimizer – небольшая утилита, которая представляет собой удобный инструмент, предназначенный для дополнительного сжатия различных файлов, посредством специального алгоритма. Она позволит сильно ускорить выполнение разного рода задач, в которых эти файлы участвуют, за счет уменьшения объема обрабатываемой информации. Поддерживается работа с широким спектром различных форматов, в том числе и с файлами AIR, APNG, APPX, DOCX, CBZ, EPUB, ICO, GIF, GZ, JAR, MNG, JPEG, MPP, PNG, PPTX, PUB, PDF, TIF, SWF, VSD, XLSX, XAP и ZIP.

Answer (score 1):

выше комментатор, я полагаю, предоставил универсальное средство.

моё мнение:
оптимизация включает в себя не только обжать файл, но выбор правильного формата и алгоритма сжатия.

так например: два одинаковых файла jpg с разницей в повороте на 90º будут иметь разный объем. что можно использовать

я по старинке использую фотошоп и sefe for web, с дальнейшими установками взависимости от целей картинки.